# dynamic cast disallowed c++

Tags: c++, dynamic, casting

hi  and sorry for long post , I m having problem , that I solved in some way, the lecturer, said that my code is wrong , I didnt understand why, the problem is as follows:

we have a lab class, for testing a virus, we have 3 kinds of customers for that lab , that each of them pays differently for getting tested, the customers are:

- `class GeneralCustomer ;// which all customers inherit from it`
- `class Customer : public GeneralCustomer // a normal customer`
- `class FamilyCustomer: public GeneralCustomer // family customer`
- `class **VipCustomer: public GeneralCustomer // VIP customer`

In that lab there are some methods and attributes , the relevant for my problem is : the method `CalculateMoney();`  and an array of `GeneralCustomers[]`.

`CalculateMoney()` calculates the amount of money that the lab has gained based on each customer type

`GeneralCustomers` array, is an array of `GeneralCustomers` that is to be used for dynamic cast later

for each type of customer the function should return a number based on that type  (normal pays an amount , family pays another amount , and vip pays another amount)

so what i did in general , is that i iterated over the GeneralCustomers array, and applied dynamic cast on each cell in the array ( dynamic cast from GeneralCustomer to normal or family or vip)
and asked if the dynamic cast succeded then the function returns based on that dynamic cast (for example if the dynamic cast succeeded to cast to vip customer then the function returns the number for vip customer ..)

the teacher wrote that my answer is wrong , because there is no polymorphism

forgive me for syntax errors, or if some things are missing, I just want to understand the core problem and why the dynamic cast is not right to use in this situation

this is the code that i wrote :

```
int calculateMoney() { // function that calculates 
    GeneralCustomer* it = customer_arr.begin(); // iterating from the start of generalCustomer array
    int sum = 0;

    while (it) {
        calculateNew(&sum, *it);
        it++;
    }
    return sum;
}
void calculateNew(int* s, GeneralCustomer* cust) {

    Customer* normal;
    FamilyCustomer* fam;
    VipCustomer* vp;

    normal = dynamic_cast<Customer*> (cust);
    fam = dynamic_cast<FamilyCustomer*> (cust);
    VipCustomer = dynamic_cast<VipCustomer*> (cust);


    if (normal) { 
        // normal customer code
    }
    else if (fam) {
        // family customer code
    }
    else {
        // vip customer code
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up vrtual functions and polymorphism.  For the most part, if you have `dynamic_cast`, you have a design flaw.

Comment: Polymorphism would have been if you had made calculate functions `virtual` member functions of your classes.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is almost always the wrong answer. `GeneralCustomer` should have a virtual function `get_cost()`, and each derived type should override it.

Comment: More immediately, although there is no code to demonstrate what's going on, if the base class doesn't have any virtual functions, `dynamic_cast` to any derived type will fail. That's probably part of what "because there is no polymorphism" refers to.

Comment: Lots of unrelated "WTF?"... the assumption that `customer_arr.begin()` is a `GeneralCustomer*` (instead of a `GeneralCustomer::iterator`). The general use of pointers. I also fear that `calculateNew()` intends to put its result into its `s` parameter instead of returning it...

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is pretty much the opposite of polymorphism. Forget that it exists, and read the introduction to polymorhism in your favourite C++ book one more time.

Comment: *the teacher wrote that my answer is wrong , because there is no polymorphism* -- The trick in knowing you're doing something wrong when it comes to polymorphism is if you write code that says `if it's this object, do this, if it's that object, do that, if it's some other object, do this other thing, if it's this fourth object, do what we do with object four,..."` etc. etc.  Look at the end of your code with those `if` statements -- you see you're going down that path.

Comment: Just curious. What does ```class **VipCustomer``` mean?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use polymorphism here instead of the dynamic cast you're currently using, consider defining the classes as follows:

```
class GeneralCustomer {
    virtual int calculate_money() const { return 100; }
};
class Customer : public GeneralCustomer {
    // here we override the virtual function from GeneralCustomer
    // with the correct amount for this type of customer
    int calculate_money() const override { return 200; }
};
class FamilyCustomer : public GeneralCustomer {
    int calculate_money() const override { return 50; }
};
// ... etc ...
```

now at runtime the correct function will be called based on which type of customer was originally created:

```
int main() {
    // create a vector of customers, this is similar to the array you have
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GeneralCustomer>> customers;
    // the first customer is a FamilyCustomer, but it's stored in the vector
    // as a generic GeneralCustomer pointer
    customers.push_back(std::make_unique<FamilyCustomer>();
    // then a VipCustomer, it'll also be stored as a GeneralCustomer
    customers.push_back(std::make_unique<VipCustomer>();
    // ... etc ...

    int total_money = 0;
    for (std::unique_ptr<GeneralCustomer>& customer : customers) {
        // this call to calculate_money() will call the correct function
        // depending on the original type that was constructed in the vector
        // above (i.e. `FamilyCustomer` instead of `GeneralCustomer`
        // for the first entry)
        total_money += customer->calculate_money();
    }
}
```

No dynamic casts needed - and everyone is still happy! Hopefully that makes sense, feel free to comment if not and I'll try to update the answers.